# Facing several issues trying to consume a GitHub package I published

Tags: maven, gradle, github-actions

I [created an SDK package today](https://github.com/MikeWarren2014/KatalonStudioSDK/packages/1868228), but for some reason I cannot seem to use it...!

### How the package was created

It is published to **GitHub packages** [under these instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-gradle-registry). I had saved personal access token to environment variable on my machine, as well as my username, under `GITHUB_TOKEN` and `GITHUB_ACTOR`, respectively.

My `build.gradle` look like :

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'maven-publish'
  id "com.katalon.gradle-plugin" version "0.1.1"
}

group = 'com.mikewarren.katalonstudiosdk'
version = '1.0'

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.javafaker:javafaker:1.0.2'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['Keywords', 'Libs']
            excludes = ['CustomKeywords.groovy', "Temp*.groovy"]
        }
    }
    test {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['Include/scripts/groovy']
        }
    }
}

publishing {
    repositories { 
        maven {
            name = "GitHubPackages"
            url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/MikeWarren2014/KatalonStudioSDK")
            credentials {
                username = project.findProperty("gpr.user") ?: System.getenv("GITHUB_ACTOR")
                password = project.findProperty("gpr.key") ?: System.getenv("GITHUB_TOKEN")
            }
        }
    }
    publications {
        gpr(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId = 'katalon-studio-sdk'
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

I also, before all this, set up a **GitHub action** to publish the package, but it did **NOT** get hit when I said `gradle clean publish --info`:

[image]

### When I try to use the package

[Here is the package in question](https://github.com/MikeWarren2014/KatalonStudioSDK/packages/1868228). I [follow GitHub's instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-gradle-registry#using-a-published-package) and hit a brick wall...

Here's the `build.gradle` for the consumer project:

```
plugins {
  id 'groovy'
  id "com.katalon.gradle-plugin" version "0.1.0"
}

repositories {
  maven {
      name = "GitHubPackages"
      url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/MikeWarren2014/KatalonStudioSDK")
      credentials {
          username = project.findProperty("gpr.user") ?: System.getenv("GITHUB_ACTOR")
          password = project.findProperty("gpr.key") ?: System.getenv("GITHUB_TOKEN")
      }
  }
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'me.mikewarren.katalonstudiosdk:katalon-studio-sdk:1.0'
}
```

When I `gradle clean build`, it "succeeds`:

[image]

However, when I search the consumer project for the `katalon-studio-sdk-1.0.jar` or `katalon-studio-sdk-1.0-all.jar`, it's nowhere!

I then remember this is a Katalon Studio project, which gives me the idea to `gradle katalonCopyDependencies`, only to be met with this:

[image]

I try to crawl the URL in my browser, and get prompted by GitHub for my credentials. Looks promising...

The page it returns for my doing so, is text page that simply says:

```
maven package "me.mikewarren.katalonstudiosdk.katalon-studio-sdk" does not exist under owner "MikeWarren2014"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**: When I run `gradle tasks --all | grep publish`

I see:

```
publish - Publishes all publications produced by this project.
publishAllPublicationsToGitHubPackagesRepository - Publishes all Maven publications produced by this project to the GitHubPackages repository.
publishGprPublicationToGitHubPackagesRepository - Publishes Maven publication 'gpr' to Maven repository 'GitHubPackages'.
publishGprPublicationToMavenLocal - Publishes Maven publication 'gpr' to the local Maven repository.
publishToMavenLocal - Publishes all Maven publications produced by this project to the local Maven cache.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package consumption issue was a PEBKAC (Problem Existing Between Keyboard And Chair)...

I had mistakenly called my package group:

```
'com.mikewarren.katalonstudiosdk'
```

but was tryna consume package with group:

```
'me.mikewarren.katalonstudiosdk'
```

Silly me! Pun intended?

Now the question remains on the GitHub Actions not working...